# svn command history for branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to a project. I want to find out how the person before me was creating branches.
How can I get the command history for SVN? That person is no longer around for me to ask.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.10.5.
I try "svn log" but that doesn't give me enough information.

I tried looking in the repo-browser.. I can see existing branches.. but not what commands were used to create the branches. I want to see what *exact* commands were used so I can use the same commands and not break the existing pattern.

Comment: I would like to use the svn command line to create branches, so that is why I want to look at this history of the commands.

Comment: Subversion doesn't store any command history. But TortoiseSVN is a GUI tool that doesn't interact with the repository via commands. I suggest you edit the question and ask about the actual problem you need solved rather than about the solution you've figured out. That way we'll possibly come up with different ideas.

Comment: Please, read the documentation at https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html.